# Spring Mvc:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

`Maven3` + `Spring 4` + `Jetty`
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name></display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vito16.activiti.demo1.config.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.vito16.activiti.demo1.config.WebConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Open Entity Manager in View filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring mvc config using annotation:

```
package com.vito16.activiti.demo1.config;

import com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSourceFactory;
import org.activiti.spring.annotations.EnableActiviti;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * @author Vito
 * @version 2014/6/4
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```

My test controller:

```
package com.vito16.activiti.demo1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * @author Vito
 * @version 2014/6/4
 */
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

when im visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index` result 404:
[image: 404]

and console print message:

```
INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/index],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vito16.activiti.demo1.controller.IndexController.index()
INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 265 ms
WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

How to fix it? I do not have this problem before using the XML configuration over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your configuration is missing

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your package to beans")
```

so it cant scan your beans like controller or whatever you try to make as bean

so add this on top of your configuration class like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vito16.activiti.demo1")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```